# How to handle Gutenberg wp.data async errors?

Tags: javascript, block-editor, endpoints

When using `wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords(...)`, there is a special selector for loading states `wp.data.select('core/data').isResolving(...)`. But what about actual errors -- backend validation errors, servers gone missing, etc? How to get the error data to present proper feedback to the user?